# Adding span/h1 styles to php

Tags: php, html, css

The below code is connected to a contact form. On submit, you receive one of two messages. How can I add span and h1 styles to these messages?

```
 <?php

    if($_GET['message'] == "thanks")  {  
        $message = "Message received! Thank you for contacting us.";
        } else {
        if($_GET['message'] == "wrongcaptcha")
        $message = "We are having problems processing your message. The captcha code you entered was incorrect.";
        }

?>


<div id="thankyoubox">
<p><?php echo $message?><p>

</div><!--end of thankyoubox-->
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does simply adding tags to the string constants work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of these two ways will work:

```
$message = '<h1 style="color:#333;font-weight:bold;" >Message received! <span>Thank you</span> for contacting us.</h1>';
```

or

```
<h1><?php echo $message?><h1>
```

Comment: Thanks...can I add h1 styles this way also? I was having a problem with this. As in <h1 style="font-family;...color;...fill in whatever;">Message received</h1>";

Comment: you were probably having trouble with escaping. I've edited my answer above to show how to add styles to it.

Answer (score 2):

Alter your `$message` variable. For example:

```
$message = "<h1>Message received!</h1> Thank you for contacting us.";
```

Comment: This would work, but you should also suggest removing the wrapping `<p>` tags around his echo.